# Loop through an array of numbers and do something 'number' of times without having two loops?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have that script :

```
var array = [1,5];

array.forEach(function(i) {
      something(i);
    });

function something(i){ 
    for(j=1; j <= i; j++) {
        console.log('item displayed ' + j + ' times');     
    }
}
```

Result is the following :

```
item displayed 1 times
item displayed 1 times
item displayed 2 times
item displayed 3 times
item displayed 4 times
```

And I wonder if I can loop through the array, as many times as the current value actually is ? To avoid having two loops.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? You _are_ looping as many times as the current value actually is

Comment: You can use map() and new Array(value).forEach((val, index) ...) if code length is the issue because I don't see how u can iterate N no. of times without having any loop

Comment: @Justinas In the second loop, yes I am, but in the first I am just looping over these two elements in my array. I'm not sure what I want to do, just thought I would like to have the simplest code possible without nested loops

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan yeah to be honnest I was using map at first and didn't seem to be able to get what I wanted, but I'm sure that has to be a solution too

Comment: Post your attempt with map. We will check and fix it.

Comment: But map() is same as forEach() in terms of iterations

Comment: I will try to summarize what I'm trying to achieve yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a second counter for the value whcih counts up to the item's value.

```js
var array = [1, 5];

for (let i = 0, j = 1; i < array.length; j < array[i] ? j++ : (j = 1, i++))
    console.log(i, j);
```

Comment: This is looking good ! Any way .map() could help me with that aswell ?

Comment: `map` or any of the other methods iterate the given items, not more maybe less like with `some` or `every`.